Django combing multiple managers from inherited classes
I have model that inherits from 2 abstract classes with overridden managers:
class ManagerA(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(attrA="A")

class A(models.Model):
  objects = ManagerA()

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class ManagerB(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(attrB="B")

class B(models.Model):
  objects = ManagerB() 

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Main(A, B):
  pass


How to override manager in Main class, that it combines both filters from ManagerA and ManagerB? I want ot have something like:
Main.objects.all() -> works like Main.objects.filter(attrA="A", attrB="B")

